# How to forward traffic to another server adhoc

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a webservice that is hosted on a server A. It is accessible via the internet. There is a public IP that is assigned to A.

In case of maintenance (of the webservice!) I would like to forward every request to another server B.

I do not have the possibility to place a sort of balancer that I can control to switch.

Whats the best way to switch all inbound traffic of a specific port from A to by B.
Is it iptables forward on A or is there a simpler tool?

I speak about all traffic - I do not need a sort of balancing between 2.

Comment: `iptables` is the tool for those tasks. It's not very complicated, you can find lots of tutorials that answer this specific question.